# Is it ok sorting a dictionary with 20 values by replacing the key?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which is used as a leader board for a sports league I change the leader board after each game I would like to know if this implementation is ok or should I be using a binary tree.

My thinking is

1. The leader board only contains 20 teams
2. As the dictionary can jump straight to the key which needs to be sorted it does not need to traverse down the tree (for example if I just need to swap the 20th and 19th positions) and stops as soon as the team ahead has more points

I know that binary trees are usually used for this sort of feature but I do not understand why it makes much of a difference if I am getting the team position via hashing.

```
    def update_table_win(self, winning_team):
    position_in_league = team_dictionary[winning_team]['league_stats']['position']  # get winning team position
    league_table[position_in_league]['points'] += 3  # update their points
    team_who_won = league_table[position_in_league]  # this is the team

    if position_in_league != 1:
        next_team_up = position_in_league - 1 # get the team ahead of the current team
        while league_table[position_in_league]['points'] > league_table[next_team_up]['points']:
            team_ahead = league_table[next_team_up]  # get the team ahead
            swap_pos = next_team_up + 1


            # swap team ahead of winning team into its position in the league
            league_table[swap_pos] = league_table[next_team_up]
            team_dictionary[team_ahead['team']]['league_stats']['position'] = swap_pos

            # as the winning team has more points than the team ahead replace it
            league_table[next_team_up] = team_who_won
            team_dictionary[team_who_won['team']]['league_stats']['position'] = next_team_up


            # decrement both indexes for next check
            next_team_up -= 1
            position_in_league -= 1
            if next_team_up == 0:  # if the next team up is equal to 0 break as it is not a key
                break
```

After each game the user can view the table in the GUI here is what the table looks like. I am using a dictionary as I will be keeping track of other stats through out the league but I suppose I can do what was said in the comments and use a tuple and use this to fetch the results from the teams dictionary.

[image: Table after sorting]

Comment: A dictionary isn't a good data structure for ordered data. It's better to use a list. You can sort the key-value pairs of a dictionary by value like so: `sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`, which gives you a list of tuples containing team name and points. Your code needs more context to run and for us to understand. Please provide a [mre] that runs and reproduces your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is great confusion in your mind. Let's clear things out.

#### Useless optimization

First of all, you are trying to optimize performance out of something that will likely be instantaneous even if you did it the worst way possible. If you have 20 teams (or even 2000 really...) you can afford sorting them each time you update their score. You won't even notice it. So yes, it's ok to do whatever you are trying to, you don't need to resort to "advanced" data structures.

#### Using a list instead of a dictionary

Second, from what I understand in your code, you are basically using a dictionary just like a list, meaning you have a dictionary whose keys are numbers from `0` to `n-1`, where `n` is the number of items in it. Even though asymptotically there is no penalty in doing so, in practice this is immensely slower than using a list. You probably didn't notice due to the first reason I mentioned.

#### An efficient solution?

Lastly, if you really wanted it to be efficient (but you probably shouldn't because it's much harder than simply re-sort the leaderboard at each update — thus harder to read, to maintain and to debug) I think you should use a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). This would allow `O(lg(n))` update in the worst case, and (probably) `O(1)` average case.

However, this does not take into account what you actually want to do with it afterwards. Imagine, after having update your leaderboard, you want to display it. This is `O(n)`, so it's useless having an efficient key modification routine. On the other hand, if you play 3 billions matches, and then display the leaderboard, it makes sense to optimize the insertion. Or maybe you just want to know who's winning, in which case a max-binary heap is the best solution. Or you want to know the top 3. You can only solve a given problem in an optimal way, not provide an optimal solution *as is*.

Comment: I'd say keep it simple. A `dict` will serve perfectly to update details (e.g. `teams[team_id]['score'] = ...`), and `sorted(teams, key=lambda team: team['score'])` will produce the leader board on the fly. Anything more complicated than has heavily diminishing returns.

Comment: Yes, that also my point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation these are some issues I have been thinking about and yes I do display the leader board each game week which is `0(n)`. I will need the teams name and points as well so should I use a list of tuples like suggested above in the comment?

Comment: I think what @Tomalak explicitly proposed is the better.
Each team should be a dictionary, with each field of the dictionary a column of your table. Then, either your whole table is a dictionary, keys being team identifiers and values being the teams. For instance, if you have team A and team B, you could have something like `teams = {"A": {"name": "Team A", "score": 40}, "B": {"name": "Team B", "score": 15}}` (it's a simplified example). Then use `sorted(...)` to retrieve the leaderboard.

Comment: The sorting method in python gives a time of O(n. logn) that is worse than my dictionary sorting the elements as O(n), I'm not trying to be a smart ass just want to learn :)

Comment: Python sorting method is O(n log n) in the general case, but works faster on almost-sorted lists. In particular, in your case, it (most likely) works in O(n), because your list is pretty much already sorted. However, you really have to get that if your list has 20 elements, it's really not the complexity that matters, but the hidden constant factor. Turns out Python sorting method also has a very small hidden constant, probably in part due to the fact that the loops are coded in C, not in Python, making it even faster (and that the algorithm is fast).